# Sql - How to fetch the single flavor recipes from a intermediate table

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

As you can see in the table below, some recipes have 2 or more flavors but some have just 1. I want to take back a table with the flavor_id and the flavor_amount of the single flavor recipes. I managed to do get back some info but i can't take the flavor_amount too..
The closest i got is with this query

```
SELECT COUNT('flavor_id') as flavors, `recipe_id`, 
MAX(flavor_id) as flavor_id 
FROM `flavor_recipe` 
GROUP BY `recipe_id` 
HAVING flavors = 1;
```

But still nothing. Any help please? Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Simply add `MAX(flavor_amount)` like `MAX(flavor_id)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gordon's answer reminded me the subqueries. So i thought to give a try and found the solution

```
SELECT `*`
FROM `flavor_recipe`
WHERE `recipe_id` IN 
   (SELECT `recipe_id` FROM `flavor_recipe` 
   GROUP BY `recipe_id` 
   HAVING COUNT(flavor_id) = 1);
```

So simple i can't believe i didn't thought of sub queries earlier.. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This might be more efficient:

```
select fr.*
from flavor_recipe fr
where not exists (select 1
                  from flavor_recipe fr2
                  where fr2.recipe_id = fr.recipe_id and fr2.flavor_id <> fr.flavor_id
                 );
```

In particular, you want an index on `flavor_recipe(recipe_id, flavor_id)`.

Comment: Nop i get nothing with this query from the table i posted :/

Comment: The second where should have `fr1.flavor_id != fr.flavor_id`.

Answer (score 0):

When you have the `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` SQL mode enabled, you can disable the aggregation check for a specific value by using the [`ANY_VALUE()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_any-value) function.

```
SELECT recipe_id, COUNT(*) AS flavors, ANY_VALUE(flavor_id) AS flavor_id
FROM flavor_recipe
GROUP BY recipe_id
HAVING flavors = 1
```

Comment: Somewhere i read about it. But i was hoping i could find a query for that. I managed to take w/e i want for statistics but this. :/

Answer (score 0):

You can ad `concat` with max and min value.
But so only you can see two ids in same column.

```
SELECT COUNT('flavor_id') as flavors, `recipe_id`, CONCAT(MIN(flavor_id), MAX(flavor_id)) as flavor_id FROM `flavor_recipe` GROUP BY `recipe_id` HAVING flavors = 1;
```